# Missing part of string while insert into mysql with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have make a form with this code:

```
<form action="action.php" method="POST">
HTML:
<textarea name="html"></textarea>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

and Insert it with php :

```
<?php
include "database.php";
$html = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['html']);
$insert = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO data VALUES('$html')");
?>
```

I have used that, and it successfully inserted to mysql, but some of my html string is missing
Example: if i insert 2000 character of html, it just insert 250 character
Note: I'm using jquery to post the form

```
$.ajax({
        url     : url_login,

        data    : 'html='+html, 

        type    : 'POST',

        dataType: 'html',

        success : function(mess){
            $('#content').html(mess);
        },
    });
```

Please help

Comment: Did you check the database field to make sure it allows more than 250 characters?

Comment: Why are you storing entire chunks of HTML data? (Yes, I know there are plenty of cases where this is fully valid, but this may be an XY problem)

Comment: yes, i have set it to longtext

Comment: Make use of prepared statements and validate `$_POST`.

Comment: Okay, thank you i have checked my POST request, no problem that i see. But after i echo the variable it show the problem, Yes it just showing just some part. I have using jquery post, What is my problem? :(

Comment: A shot in the dark but what if you put your data as `data : {html: html}`?

Comment: but, i also post another data too. so how i put it into my jquery code?

Comment: It may be an issue of the html tag characters screwing up the parameters sent to the back end. Are you using urlencode and urldecode at all?

Comment: no, i'm not use it

Comment: Hey after i read about that, and use it into my script IT WORKS! Thank you very much @Script47

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…”)` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk. Using bound parameters is less verbose and easier to review to check you’re doing it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should follow the format as mentioned by jQuery AJAX [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

change,

```
data    : 'html='+html,
```

to,

```
data : { 
    html: html
}
```

The format that is being use is known as a [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) where you specify key/values (as many as you'd like).

**Note**

1. Seeing as you are using `mysqli_*` consider usng [prepared
   statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) to prevent
   SQL injection.
2. Validate your `$_POST` with [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) and [`empty`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) to ensure that the fields are set to prevent errors.

Comment: Not only is this easier to read, but it properly escapes the content in `html`.